# Profile and MembershipUser complex view model design

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-3, viewmodel

I have a part of my mvc 3 web app, where I need to allow users (admins in this case) to manage users.  The admin will be able to edit the user's profile info, as well as certain .NET Membership properties such as UserName, Email, IsLockedOut.  The part I am struggling with is how to best wrap that all into a custom model.

Currently I have a Profile object like so:

```
 public class Profile
    {
        public int ProfileID { get; set; }
        public Guid UserID { get; set; }  // link to membership user ID
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string Phone { get; set; }
    }
```

My first thought was to do something like this:

```
public class ProfileUser
    {
        public ProfileUser(Profile profile)
        {
            Profile = profile;
            User = Membership.GetUser(profile.UserID);
        }

        public Profile Profile { get; set; }
        public MembershipUser User { get; set; }
    }
```

But since some fields are read-only in the MembershipUser class, I wouldn't be able to directly pass the model back to the controller with the new values for the UserName or IsLockedOut field to update the DB with.

Then I thought about just making essentially a wrapper for both classes as one class:

```
public class ProfileUser : Profile
{
    public ProfileUser(Profile profile)
    {
        this.ProfileID = profile.ProfileID;
        this.UserID = profile.UserID;
        this.FirstName = profile.FirstName;
        this.LastName = profile.LastName;
        this.Phone = profile.Phone;
    }

    private string userName;
    public string UserName
    {
        get
        {
            if (userName == null)
            {
                userName = Membership.GetUser(this.UserID).UserName;
            }
            return userName;
        }
        set
        {
            userName = value;
        }
    }

    private string email;
    public string Email
    {
        get
        {
            if (email == null)
            {
                email = Membership.GetUser(this.UserID).Email;
            }
            return email;
        }
        set
        {
            email = value;
        }
    }

    private bool? isLockedOut;
    public bool? IsLockedOut
    {
        get
        {
            if (isLockedOut == null)
            {
                isLockedOut = Membership.GetUser(this.UserID).IsLockedOut;
            }
            return isLockedOut;
        }
        set
        {
            isLockedOut = value;
        }
    }
}
```

If I do it this way, I could pass the values as the admin entered them back to the model and do my own magic to update those read-only fields in the DB, but I am not sure if I am implementing this class the best way.

**Disclaimer**: I realize the best route to go is to probably make a custom membership or profile provider, but for reasons out of my hands, I cannot go that way.  In all of these examples I would be retrieving the profile object from the DB, which will already have the UserID linked from their Membership record.

Any direction on this would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks in advance for taking the time to help.